# Mobile safari,tap and hold a link,it will show a gray shadow,how to disable it?

Tags: css, web-applications, mobile-safari

every single link in iOS mobile safari, when be tapped and held, it will show a gray shadow,like a label, is there any way to disable it or custom it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple css property for this

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```